# Can I ask for passage reviews in this community?

Tags: discussion

Does this community allow requests of whole passage reviews? Or should I only ask more specific questions here?
If this isn't the right community, is there another community for passage reviews on the Stack Exchange network?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [meta] for questions about the site. See the [tour] and [ask] for an introduction and how to ask questions. See [help] for more detailed help.  In short, no what you ask for is proofreading, and that is off topic here.

Comment: The goal of this site is to build a library of answers that will be helpful to many people learning English, not to tutor individual learners. If the question you’re asking is “explain this paragraph to me”, that is unlikely to help anyone except you. If your question is similar to “I looked up this word but none of the meanings seem to fit in this sentence”, that could help other people that come across that word used in that way in other sentences.

Answer (score 5):

No.

This is considered to be "proofreading", and is not accepted. You can't paste an English text and ask "is it correct".

The help guide states:

> Please don’t ask any questions about ... proofreading (for example, "Are there any mistakes?" or "Is this correct?"), unless a source of concern is clearly specified

What you should do is ask a specific question: Identify the specific feature that you have a difficulty with, explain why you doubt the correctness of this part. Show that you have already tried to answer your question using reasonable resources (for example you must use a dictionary if you are asking about meanings and you should reference a grammar guide if you are asking about grammar)

Provide enough context, but don't paste your entire essay. Tell us who you are writing for (school, work, fiction, email, etc)

Good questions inspire answers that explain “why” and “how” and not just Yes or No.